At a technical level, what obstacles prevent annotations from having default methods with actual logic?
Annotations in Java have functions -- which behave like properties or fields in some ways -- which may have default values.  For example:
public @interface Foo {
  int value() default 1;
}

However, annotations cannot have methods with actual bodies, even marked default.
public @interface Foo {
  int value() default 1;

  default int add(int addend) { // NOT ALLOWED
    return value() + addend;
  }
}

The Java Language Specification specifies that this is forbidden in section 9.6.1:

By virtue of the grammar above, a method declaration in an annotation interface declaration cannot have formal parameters, type parameters, or a throws clause; and cannot be private, default, or static. Thus, an annotation interface cannot have the same variety of methods as a normal interface.

What technical reasons exist making this difficult or impossible to support, if any?  I am not asking why the Java designers might have decided they didn't want to support this -- I'm perfectly aware that's not a good question for StackOverflow -- but only if there are specific known problems that might block the JDK developers from adding such a feature.

I can't think of any technical reasons, but there are plenty of non-technical ones :)

As stated in the comments there are plenty of non-technical reasons why annotations in Java don't allow methods with bodies. I believe that on a technical level there are very few limitations for what can be done with the language, but technical limitations define more than just features, they encompass the overall structure of the programming language and how it performs.
The following are, in my opinion, some of the reasons that touch technical aspects of the Java language on this topic:

Annotations are meant to be lightweight metadata descriptors. If they were allowed to have method bodies, they would start overlapping with interfaces, which already handle behavior-related logic. This would blur the distinction between the two constructs and reduce the clarity of their respective roles in the language. On a technical level it becomes more and more difficult to justify the existence of both.

The JVM already has mechanisms for managing both annotations and interfaces. If annotations were allowed to have method bodies, the JVM would need to treat them similarly to interfaces in terms of bytecode structure, method dispatching, and execution. This would complicate the JVM's internal handling of annotations, which are currently very lightweight. In contrast, the JVM’s handling of interfaces involves more work, like method resolution and runtime method invocation, which would now be required for annotations too.


In summary, while it may initially appear to be a design choice that annotations are metadata rather than behavior, this choice leads to technical constraints and limitations at the language and JVM level. Overcoming these limitations would require changing how annotations are implemented, compiled, and executed, which is why the distinction is not just a matter of preference but also of technical feasibility within the existing architecture of Java.
I believe that "keep things simple and extensible" is a good technical reason to avoid implementing such features in a language.
